# copying sql server to another location

Tags: sql-server-2005, copy, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to copy my db including data from sql server 2008 R2 to another sql server (sql express 2005). I noticed that backup cannot be done from later version to earlier version. What is the best approach I should take?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are copying from higher version to lower version,its not possible to get it done in one shot.

The best way is to transfer the tables with data using SSIS.

Comment: as for the moment I gave it a shot using generate script. I just hope it won't fail because of the express version. What is SSIS?

Comment: SQL Server Integration Services